# Why does this console log twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, monads, console.log

### What I'm trying to do:

I want to use Node to fire up two child processes in a particular order at a particular time, console logging their `stdout` as they stream, occasionally switching between the two.

#### The output I want:

```
`Proc 1 log # 1`
`Proc 1 log # 2`
`Proc 1 log # 3`
`Proc 1 log # 4`
`Proc 2 log # 1`
`Proc 2 log # 2`
`Proc 2 log # 3`
`Proc 2 log # 4`
`Proc 1 log # 9`
`Proc 1 log # 10`
`Proc 1 log # 11`
`Proc 1 log # 12`
`Proc 1 log # 13`
`Proc 1 log # 14`
`Proc 1 log # 15`
`All procs have finished!`
```

Of course it's super easy to do. *Imperatively*. But it's also really ugly & stateful and just urgh. So I'm trying to do it purely, and have built up the computation using the [`Task`](https://github.com/folktale/data.task#readme) monad from folktale (the old one, that is), threading through a stateful object by hand like a chump:

```
//    main _ :: Task error {childProcs}
const main = startProc1({})
  .chain(logUntilProc1IsReady)
  .chain(startProc2)
  .chain(logUntilProc2IsReady)
  .chain(logUntilProc1IsFinished)
```

Much prettier. It would be much better too, if it worked!

#### The output I get:

```
`Proc 1 log # 1`                                       
`Proc 1 log # 2`
`Proc 1 log # 3`
`Proc 1 log # 4`
`Proc 2 log # 1`
`Proc 1 log # 6`   // <-- These should not be logged
`Proc 2 log # 2`
`Proc 1 log # 7`
`Proc 2 log # 3`
`Proc 1 log # 8`
`Proc 2 log # 4`
`Proc 1 log # 9`
`Proc 1 log # 10`  // <-- now it's logging twice! :confounded:
`Proc 1 log # 10`
`Proc 2 log # 6`
`Proc 1 log # 11`
`Proc 1 log # 11`
`Proc 2 log # 7`
`Proc 1 log # 12`
`Proc 1 log # 12`
`Proc 2 log # 8`
`Proc 1 log # 13`
`Proc 1 log # 13`
`Proc 2 log # 9`
`Proc 1 log # 14`
`Proc 1 log # 14`
`Proc 2 log # 10`
`All procs have finished!`
```

#### Stuff I've done:

Here is the logging function:

```
//    logStreamUntil :: int -> (a -> bool) -> proc -> string -> Task error State () {childProcs}
const logStreamUntil = curry((predFunc, procName, procObj) => 
  new Task ((_, res) => {
    const proc = procObj[procName]
    const logUntilPred = data =>
      predFunc(data) 
        ? (rmAllListeners(proc), res(procObj))
        : console.log(data)
    proc.stdout.on('data', logUntilPred)
}))
```

Of which the tl;dr: is that I'm sending it a process name and the object to pluck the actual child-process from, as well as a predicate function used to decide for how long to console log the `stdout` of whichever child-process had been thrown at it. The predicates just look for something specific in the string from `stdout`. So it console logs the output when the predicate function returns false, else it stops logging, removes the listener and that should be that!

And here then is the `rmAllListeners` function:

```
//    rmAllListeners :: childProc -> childProc           
const rmAllListeners = proc => (proc.removeAllListeners(), proc.stdout.unref())
```

Which latter is clearly the issue. Listeners, despite being namespaced and supposedly obliterated by the above, are not being. And I don't know why?!? Help!

#### Further reading:

There's a repo of it too for those interested in seeing the entire thing: [you can find it here](https://github.com/gskapka/func-log).

Comment: A very nicely asked question!  Kudos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing listeners from the `proc` instead of from `stdout`. The doubles are appearing because you're attaching a second copy of your listener to the 'data' events on the `proc.stdout`.

Adding `.stdout` in `rmAllListeners` fixes it for me:

```
diff --git a/why-log-twice.js b/why-log-twice.js
index 276d15c..6c15467 100644
--- a/why-log-twice.js
+++ b/why-log-twice.js
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ const PROC_ONE_PATH = `node child-proc "Proc 1 log # "`
 const PROC_TWO_PATH = `node child-proc "Proc 2 log # "`

 //    rmAllListeners :: childProc -> childProc           
-const rmAllListeners = proc => (proc.removeAllListeners(), proc.stdout.unref())
+const rmAllListeners = proc => (proc.stdout.removeAllListeners(), proc.stdout.unref())

 //    procIsReady :: string -> bool
 const procIsReady = str => str.includes('5')
```

Comment: So simple! Bit of a forehead-slapper really in hindsight. Especially since I'd managed to correctly unref the bleeding `stdout` right next to it. Sigh. 

I'm quite relieved it was nothing to do with the Task computation/fp stuff though! Thank you so much!

Comment: So many answers are forehead-slappers (yours or your co-worker's!) in hindsight.  We all get stuck like this.  A very nice question, and a well-done answer.  Glad to have you aboard here on SO!